# How to check does exist table in database and if not, make now? C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

What is the easiest way to check if table exists in database and if there not make a new one.

I know to make new table but I don't know check.....

I'm using C#,visual studio 2013, and mysql ( on wamp )

Comment: By if-else / try-catch and some SqlCommand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `CREATE TABLE` use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

As you can see the `IF NOT EXISTS` part is optional, so just make it exactly like your create table statement which you said you know how to do and add that before the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Other way

code :

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
string myConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                        "DATABASE=mydatabase;" +
                        "UID=user;" +
                        "PASSWORD=mypassword;";

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SHOW TABLES;";
MySqlDataReader Reader;
connection.Open();
Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (Reader.Read())
{
 string row = "";
for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
    row += Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ", ";
Console.WriteLine(row);
}
connection.Close();
```

You can probably store it in the List and check with property List.Contains

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string connectionString = "Connection String";

using (var command = new MySqlCommand { Connection = connectionString })
{
      conn.Open();

      command.CommandText = @"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `TableName`;
                              CREATE TABLE `TableName`....";
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```